# Gerar relatório PDF com o jasper reports e spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Olá,

Estou com um problema ao gerar um relatório com o jasper reports no spring.

Fiz a implementação exatamente como consta no método 4 dessa explicação: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532493

Quando clico no botão para gerar o relatório, sou redirecionado para o link conforme o @RequestMapping e o navegador carrega o relatório no leitor de pdf interno do navegador.. ai que começa o problema..

No desktop, como os navegadores tem o leitor de pdf interno, ele é carregado mas quando vou salvar, o arquivo nem tem um nome definido (fica sempre como document.pdf).

Se tento gerar esse mesmo relatório por um celular (estou testando em um android), é aberto o leitor de pdf que esta instalado e em seguida da erro falando que o formato não é suportado. Quando eu forço um download do link, é baixado um arquivo sem formato (se eu colocar a extensão .pdf no arquivo ele abre normalmente).

Eu consigo mudar alguma coisa nessa implementação para que quando clicar no botão de gerar o relatório, seja direcionado direto para o arquivo .pdf gerado para que funcione tanto no desktop quanto no mobile ou para esse caso tenho que fazer uma implementação mais "bruta" como o método 1 do link (que acho que deve funcionar pois define o nome e tipo de arquivo direto no response) ?

vlw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o browser não está recebendo um nome para o arquivo recebido. Eu já vi sistemas one o "nome" de todos os relatórios salvos era `relatorio.jsp` porque esta era uma view que enviava o conteúdo.

No seu caso, você pode usar o método [`JasperReportsViewResolver.setHeaders()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsViewResolver.html#setHeaders-java.util.Properties-) para adicionar os cabeçalhos como no método 1 do link citado.

Exemplo:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=meuRelatorioLegal.pdf")
resolver.setHeaders(p);
```

Comment: colocando essas propriedades (adicionei também  `p.setProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");`, resolveu a questão do nome do arquivo, e se forçar o download baixa o arquivo corretamente com a extensão e tudo. pelo celular quando ele tenta carregar o leitor de pdf diretamente, ainda da erro falando que não conseguiu abrir o arquivo pdf por estar em um formato invalido.  Mas ainda ficou uma duvida, colocando essas propriedades no resolver, eu não conseguiria mudar o nome do arquivo de acordo com o relatório, certo? ou consigo passar esse nome pelo controller?

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco o `Content-disposition` aqui e descobri que see no lugar do `inline` colocar `attachment` o navegador força o download do arquivo. Fazendo isso passou a funcionar no celular também, pois passa a forçar o download ao in vez de tentar carregar no navegador. Fica mais a questão mesmo se consigo passar esse nome do arquivo pelo controller. Se der para colocar para o nome do filename ser igual ao do arquivo .jasper também seria uma boa saida.